# Graphics.DrawString centre text on printed page

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using the following to print out some text from my C# WPF app:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\\\servername\\printername";

        printDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
        if (printDocument.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }

    // The PrintPage event is raised for each page to be printed. 
    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        string stringToPrint = "SOME TEXT TO PRINT";

        // Create font and brush.
        Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);

        System.Drawing.Point pos = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);

        ev.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, drawFont, drawBrush, pos);

        ev.HasMorePages = false;
    }
```

The above example is using a fixed position but I need to print out several lines of text all different lengths and I want to centre them all on the page (The x position).

How can I do this?

Comment: @Amit, that's not exactly a helpful reply...Harry Boy, what you would need to is determine the width of your page, the width of your image and then half the width of your page, half the width of your image, and set the X coordinate to half of the page minus half of the image width.

Comment: Thanks @mituw16 I thought maybe there would be a simple .net function for this. I will do what you suggested. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overload of [`Graphics.DrawString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx) that  uses a StringFormat parameter that you can use to set the horizontal and vertical alignment of the text in the rectangle.  I have used something like this in the past.

```
string stringToPrint = "SOME TEXT TO PRINT";
StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

// Create font and brush.
Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);

//Starting point of left margin,Width of page, Height of Text
System.Drawing.RectangleF rect = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 100, 100, 50); 

ev.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, drawFont, drawBrush, rect, sf);

ev.HasMorePages = false;
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error:  ** Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.RectangleF' to 'System.Drawing.Point'  **

Comment: Did you use the overload that I linked to, it takes RectangleF, sounds like you are still using the original which took a point.

Comment: I changed your line:  System.Drawing.Point rect = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 100, 100, 50); to System.Drawing.RectangleF rect = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 100, 100, 50); and it now works thanks

Comment: Sorry about, didn't see the typo. Will fix. Glad it helped.